# Blurred Decoration Image in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the background of my app set like so:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          image: new DecorationImage(
            image: new ExactAssetImage('assets/lol/aatrox.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: new BackdropFilter(filter: new ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 600.0, sigmaY: 1000.0)),
        width: 400.0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm wanting to blur the `DecorationImage`, so I added a `BackdropFilter` to the Container, but I don't see any change. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You could do something like this, by blurring the container child instead.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          image: new DecorationImage(
            image: new ExactAssetImage('assets/dog.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: new BackdropFilter(
          filter: new ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
          child: new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you explain this?

Comment: You can blur the container child instead of the image

Comment: @MadeBaruna can i make the BoxDecoration image clickeble

Comment: @user123456 yes, by wrapping it with InkWell widget (for a material splash efffect) or GestureDetector for more flexibility but no special effects

Comment: If want dog.png fadein cat.png  this method does not seem to be possible

Comment: if more than you want gets blurred, you have to clip the BackdropFilter widget: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56405776/10210069

Comment: You have to import 'dart:ui' for the code to work

Answer (score 62):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Using `Stack`:**

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  child: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: [
      Image.asset('chocolate_image', fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ClipRRect( // Clip it cleanly. 
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text('CHOCOLATE'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

---

**Without using `Stack`:**

```dart
Container(
  height: 200,
  width: double.maxFinite,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: ExactAssetImage("your_chocolage_image"),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
  child: ClipRRect( // make sure we apply clip it properly
    child: BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
        child: Text(
          "CHOCOLATE",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I don't know why that chocolate text will not appear in iOS after I update to Flutter to 2.2.1

Comment: there is actually a bug from flutter, it will not appear if there is a Google map on the page that has Backdropfilter. only on iOS.  here is the issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56789

Comment: Tks bro, u just save me :D

Answer (score 41):

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65739034/12483095), you should wrap your `ImageFiltered` widget in a `ClipRRect` to prevent it from flowing out the widget boundaries. Here's the code:

```dart
ClipRRect(
  child: ImageFiltered(
    imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3, sigmaY: 3),
    child: Image.asset('assets/flutter_image.png'),
  ),
),
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: This is the exact solution I need. I have to prevent it from flowing out the widget boundaries.

Comment: The Simplest , Thank you bro

Answer (score 7):

[**ImageFiltered**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImageFiltered-class.html) is the perfect widget for that . It creates a widget that applies an [**ImageFilter**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ImageFilter-class.html) to its child.
[**ImageFilter**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ImageFilter-class.html)  is an easy way to blur or transform pixels in your app . You can import it from `dart:ui`
**Code :**

```
ImageFiltered(
  imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaY:5,sigmaX:5), //SigmaX and Y are just for X and Y directions
  child: Image.asset('assets/image.png') //here you can use any widget you'd like to blur .
    )
```

> [**ImageFilter.blur()**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ImageFilter/ImageFilter.blur.html) make anything blurry  and
> [**ImageFilter.matrix()**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ImageFilter/ImageFilter.matrix.html) lets you use any matrix for
> transformation ,scaling , translating , skewing and rotating

**Output :**

[image]

> A similar widget to **[ImageFiltered](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImageFiltered-class.html)** is **[BackdropFilter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html)** .
> **BackdropFilter** lets you apply filter to everything that's painted
> beneath a widget , instead of applying the filter to the widget
> itself.
> **It's also less performant . If you can do your effect with
> [ImageFiltered](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImageFiltered-class.html) , Use it instead of [BackdropFilter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html).**

You can learn more about **[ImageFiltered](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImageFiltered-class.html)** by watching this **[official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Lftorq4i2o&t=26s)** or by visiting **[flutter.dev](https://www.flutter.dev)**

Answer (score 4):

It's better if you put in `ClipRRect`, like this :

```
Container(
    child: ClipRRect(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
          placeholder: placeholder,
          image: thumbnail,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          BackdropFilter(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black12,
            ),
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaY: 10, sigmaX: 10),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
    width: double.infinity,
  ),
```

This case apply for Image (Thumbnail) list items correctly.

Answer (score 2):

All the above answers are correct, I'll reply to @user123456 here since I can't comment yet.

> can i make the BoxDecoration image clickeble – user123456

Just wrap the whole Container with a GestureDetector

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {...},
    child: Container(
        ...
        decoration: BoxDecoration(...),
    ),           
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Image` widget. It's very simple.

```
 Image(
                        image: AssetImage("assets/images/news-media.png"),
                        color: Colors.black,
                        colorBlendMode: BlendMode.softLight,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
```