# Why does Backdrop filter blur my entire app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to achieve a very similar effect to what was shown in the widget of the week video on flutter's channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYRs7Q1vfYI#t=1m20s

On the right you see the desired result, on the left you see what's currently going on in my app.
[image: On the right my app, on the left the wanted result]

The code I've been using is pretty similar to the one from the example video, using a Stack to position the Backdrop filter over my image. The rounded image and the blur over it are inside one widget, which will is placed inside another stack (along with the text at the bottom). Since I applied the filter only a small section of the image, I don't understand why entire app is blurred. Here's the code for the Image Widget:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 75;
    return Container(
      height: size,
      width: size,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image(imageUri: "...", size: size - 30), // this is just a container with the image
          Positioned(
            top: 100,
            left: 100,
            bottom: 100,
            right: 100,
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                sigmaX: 5,
                sigmaY: 5,
              ),
              child: Container(
                color: Color(0x66FF0000),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this issue appeared with me on ios only !!!

Answer (score 114, accepted):

It turns out the video is missing an important part from the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html):

> If there's no clip, the filter will be applied to the full screen.

So the solution is to wrap the filter into a ClipRect, as taken from the example:

```
ClipRect(  // <-- clips to the 200x200 [Container] below
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(
            sigmaX: 5.0,
            sigmaY: 5.0,
          ),
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 200.0,
            height: 200.0,
            child: Text('Hello World'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I write an article to show how to make blur effect on Flutter by using BackdropFilter & ImageFilter - read it [on Medium](https://medium.com/fluttervn/how-to-make-blur-effect-in-flutter-using-backdropfilter-imagefilter-559ffd8ab73?source=friends_link&sk=044ab21dd506a6146624ec3758b0d1b4)

Comment: This answer should get a medal 

Comment: OMG ... Thank you so much - that was driving me crazy!

Comment: The fact that the Flutter team hasn't included this IS BAD. THANK YOU for saving my life.

Comment: What is `ui` here?

Comment: ClipRect is more expansive , you can check this in the profile mode , please see @hungtran273 answer

Comment: Worked perfectly when used ClipRect, thanks a lot!

Comment: I intentionally log in to thank you!

Answer (score 11):

**Another solution in 2021:**

Apply `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` to parent of BackdropFilter

```
Container(
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
  child: BackdropFilter(
    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2.0, sigmaY: 2.0),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
    ),
  ),
)
```

**Explanation:**
`clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` means `overflow: none`
If no clip, filter will overflow upward (in widget tree) until they meet clip.

Comment: I don't think this works unless the `Container` also has `decoration` set.

Comment: from profile mode ... i can tell: this answer is better than selected one , CliprRect is more expansive

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simply wrap the "BackDropFilter" with "CliprRect" widget. Like this:

```
CliprRect(child: BackDropFilter(child: "your widget"),),
```