# Masked Blur for Image

Tags: flutter

I would like to implement the effect shown below in which most parts of an image are blurred and only the interesting part of the image is shown crisp (with a border).

[image: Image Blur Cut out]

I am not sure how to implement the effect and would like to consider your ideas. Blurring the image is not the problem (i am doing it as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055676/blurred-decoration-image-in-flutter)), but leaving a part of the image non-blurred is quite a challenge. I thought about layering two images (one blurred and one non-blurred) over each other. However that will not work because then the blurred image will cast a shadow over the cutout section.

I also tried to use a CustomPainter, however i failed to get the blur working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This** is how you can do it , The idea is to make `CustomClipper` to invert the behavior of the `BackDropFilter.`

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        height: 250,
        child: Stack(

          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
                child: Image.network(
                    'https://cdn-prod.medicalnewstoday.com/content/images/articles/322/322736/elephant-from-the-front.jpg')),
            Center(
              child: ClipPath(
                clipper: InvertedRect(),
                child: BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
                  child:   Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InvertedRect extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  getClip(Size size) {
    print(size);
    return Path()
      ..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height))
      ..addRect(Rect.fromLTWH(100.0, 40.0, 100, 100))
      ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this easy and working solution. With this approach it is equally easy to apply the rectangle with a Custom Painter.

Comment: @Jens so if you need `CustomPainter` anyway then why dont you draw everything in it? that way you would need only one widget: `CustomPaint` - did you run the code i posted? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: @pskink you have a completely valid point and i will look into your method as well when refactoring the code and then decide which suits me better (but it's probably yours). Right now i am happy that the solution provided by Saed works.

Comment: @pskink sorry i was on vacation and just wanted to try your code, but i guess you removed it? In case you want to share your code please submit it as an answer i will check it out for sure!

Comment: hello @pskink this is Saed Nabil, I think that we don't need to use custom paint  to draw simple red rectangle , you simply can use a container with border and transparent color . Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jens https://gist.github.com/pskink/481825d2e4504479e1c585fdbcbc8d0a

Comment: what's the difference if it's custom clipper or custom painter? run the code I posted and you will see the difference...

Comment: I checked your code but still doesn't get it , did you mean the listener part? this can be implemented also , I just want to know if there is a difference in performance between your approach and mine i.e. between custom clipper and custom painter?

Comment: @pskink I will checkout your code tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: @SaedNabil your code is perfect for what I was asked (the masked blur). However, the solution of pskink might be superior *in my special case* (masked blur with rectangle) because it leaves less space for errors and bugs if everything is accomplished in one widget.