# ImageFiltered vs BackdropFilter; what's the difference?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

What's the difference between `ImageFiltered` and `BackdropFilter`, they both seem to do the same job. Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ImageFiltered` is more simpler to use than the `BackdropFilter` and is also recommended if you are only going to apply filters to your child widget.

Unlike `BackdropFilter` which applies filter (using its `child` property) on top of the underlying widget, `ImageFiltered` only applies the filter on the `child` widget. To better understand, please consider following example.

You'll find that in case of `ImageFiltered`, the filter is applied on the image itself. However, in case of `BackdropFilter` (this is generally used with a `Stack` but I used it in the `Column`) the `child` (here `BackdropFilter` text) is drawn over the background (Flutter image).

It is also worth noting that I'm wrapping both the filters in `ClipRRect` to prevent the blur from coming out of the container box.

[image]

```dart
class FooPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('ImageFiltered'),
          ClipRRect(
            child: ImageFiltered(
              imageFilter: _imageFilter,
              child: _image, // Above image filter is applied on the child itself.  
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          ClipRRect(
            child: Container(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              height: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: _image.image)), // Background
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: _imageFilter,
                child: Center(child: Text('BackdropFilter')), // Foreground
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Image get _image => Image.asset(flutterImage);

  ImageFilter get _imageFilter => ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you understand [material backdrop](https://material.io/components/backdrop) then it's easy to figure out the difference

The most typical usage is for a Modal, take a look at [Bootstrap Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).

The dimmed layer beneath your modal content is backdrop, which you can click to dimiss the modal.

So difference is:

ImageFiltered **blurs the whole widget** you wrapped in ImageFiltered, while BackdropFilter **blurs the content beneath** the widget you wrapped in BackdropFilter.