# Blur Image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, widget, stack, blur

I am new to flutter.
I want to make a .png image blurry in flutter which is in a container. For that I used the below mentioned code. But the blur effect is applied to the whole screen.

I used the following code :

```
child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 18, right: 18, top: 7, bottom: 7),
                  width: _width,

                  child: Stack(
                    children : [ 
                      Image.asset('assets/classes.png',
                            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                            ),
                      Positioned.fill(
                        child: BackdropFilter(
                          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 4,sigmaY: 4),
                          child: Container(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
                          )
                        )
                    ]
                    ),

                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]),
```

Comment: Wrap Image in BackDropFilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this package in `pub.dev`

https://pub.dev/packages/blur

Also, you could find a good solution in the answers to this question:

[Blurred Decoration Image in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055676/blurred-decoration-image-in-flutter)

Comment: I tried the first option by adding blur dependency in my code, and it worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

I believe the image should be the child of the backdrop filter